# program does not delete file when launched from shortcut

Tags: .net, vb.net, io

i have a small problem which is having big consequences.
whenever i launch my application from a shortcut it says that a file already exists in that location. the code i'm using is this:

```
Dim myfile As String = "HyperCredit.exe"

If System.IO.File.Exists(myfile) = True Then
    Dim fi As New FileInfo(myfile)
    fi.Delete()
End If

My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://hypercredit.co.uk/HyperCredit.exe", "C:\Program Files\HyperCredit\HyperCredit.exe")
Shell("HyperCredit.exe")

Me.Close()
```

As you can see this shouldn't happen because it deletes the file then download it.
The weird thing is the fact that it works fine just as it should when i launch the application from the exe, this only happens when i launch it from the shortcut

can someone please help me out?
Thanks

Edit: im getting this error mydirectory is not declared, it may be inaccessible due to its prptection level

```
Dim myfile As String = "HyperCredit.exe"

If System.IO.File.Exists(myfile) = True Then
    Dim fi As New FileInfo(myfile)
    fi.Delete()
End If

Dim pf As System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))

My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://hypercredit.co.uk/HyperCredit.exe", pf & "\HyperCredit.exe")
Shell("HyperCredit.exe")

Me.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, the file actually does *not* exist from the app's working directory, which could be very different from what your code assumes when it tries to download.

Assuming the WD is in C:\Program Files is a mistake. On a 64 bits machine for example, that path could very well be Program Files **(x32)** if your app is a 32 bits application. Also, what if the system is installed on D: rather than C:?

<s>You should instead use `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` to dynamically retrieve the app's working directory and THEN use that as your file root directory.</s>

**EDIT:**

You may want to use this instead:

`System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))`

This will give you your executable assembly's regardless of any shortcut's working directory. Likely you will prefer that.

Here how it should look like in your code:

```
Dim myfile As String = "HyperCredit.exe"
Dim myDirectory As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))
Dim myFullPath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(myDirectory, myFile)

If System.IO.File.Exists(myFullPath) Then
    System.IO.File.Delete(myFullPath)
End If

My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://hypercredit.co.uk/HyperCredit.exe", myFullPath)

Shell(myFullPath)
```

Comment: this application and the other application both are in the same directory, ill have a try though

Comment: @user3423954 I can't understand how you can have the same problem. Please update your question with your updated code. There might be a subtle problem left in it.

Comment: @user3423954 You are still not looking if the file exists at the right location! Look at my code: I first determine what the full path is and *then* I use it for both deletion (if necessary) and downloading.

Comment: SUCCESS it works! but another error, access is denied

Comment: @user3423954 you will have to save your file at some other place where you are certain user has privileges. If you can't do that for some reason and need help, you'd better be starting a new post. In the meantime, since this answer helped you, I advise that you mark it as your post's answer. Thanks. :)